# Foundation close button inside Reveal Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation

I use Foundation 6 and the close button http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/close-button.html 
inside jQuery Reveal Modal Plugin http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/reveal.html .

When i click on the close button of the table row, the whole modal will close, too.

How can i make the close button remove only the table row without closing the modal?

My HTML:

```
[![<div class="reveal" id="wishlist" data-reveal>
  <p class="lead">Ihre Wunschliste</p>

  <div class="wishlist">

<div data-hook="cart_container">
  <table class="stack articles">
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="callout" data-closable>
      <td>CHF 199.00
        <div class="nile-close-button">
          <span class="close-button" aria-label="Dismiss alert" type="button" data-close>
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;
              <div class="close-button-text">entfernen</div>
            </span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="callout" data-closable>
      <td>CHF 179.00
        <div class="nile-close-button">
          <span class="close-button" aria-label="Dismiss alert" type="button" data-close>
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;
              <div class="close-button-text">entfernen</div>
            </span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>][1]][1]
```

[image: modal]

It doesn't seem possible to override `data-close` handling in Foundation. So I ended up with removing Foundation's Close Button and make one myself.

Comment: From what I saw in the docs, I could not find a way to specify which element you bind the close button to, like Bootstrap does. This would imply that Foundation should take care of binding each element with `data-close` to its nearest `data-closable` parent element, but judging from your case, it doesn't? In this case I would try doing `e.stopPropagation()` when you click in the internal `x` buttons, so as not to bubble up to the modal. That may not work either, depending on how Foundation does the closing.

Comment: i did try $( "span.close-button" ).click(function( event ) {
  event.stopPropagation();
}); but without success.